# why Not enough tapbar space?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, tabbar

can you tell me why I don't have enough space at the bottom? I gave enough height to the container, but even if it is increased to 500, the error will not go away. What's my mistake?

My code -

```
DefaultTabController(
               length: 5,
               child: SingleChildScrollView(
                 child: Container(
               height: 150,
               child:  TabBar(
                 isScrollable: true,
                 tabs: [
                   Tab(child: Column(
                     children: [
                       InkWell(
                         onTap: () async {
                           print('asdasda');
                         },
                         child:  Container(
                           width: 71,
                           height: 71,
                           decoration: BoxDecoration(
                               color: Colors.white,
                               shape: BoxShape.circle
                           ),
                           child: IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: Icon(Icons.phone_iphone, size: 30, color: configColors.homeIcon,)),
                         ),
                       ),
                       Text('Phonesss')
                     ],
                   ),),
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To increase the height on Tab, you need to provide height on Tab.

```dart
return Tab(
  height: 150, //this
  child: Column(
    children: [
```

Comment: Glad to help, you can explore more about [tabs](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/tabs)

Answer (score 2):

Give height to your `Tab`

```
DefaultTabController(
               length: 5,
               child: SingleChildScrollView(
                 child: Container(
               height: 150,  // may remove
               child:  TabBar(
                 height: 150, // give height
                 isScrollable: true,
                 tabs: [
                   Tab(child: Column(
                     children: [
                       InkWell(
                         onTap: () async {
                           print('asdasda');
                         },
                         child:  Container(
                           width: 71,
                           height: 71,
                           decoration: BoxDecoration(
                               color: Colors.white,
                               shape: BoxShape.circle
                           ),
                           child: IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: Icon(Icons.phone_iphone, size: 30, color: configColors.homeIcon,)),
                         ),
                       ),
                       Text('Phonesss')
                     ],
                   ),),
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap `Text` widget with `FittedBox` like below:

```
DefaultTabController(
  length: 5,
  child: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Container(
      height: 150,
      child: TabBar(
        isScrollable: true,
        tabs: List.generate(
          5,
          (index) => Tab(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: InkWell(
                    onTap: () async {
                      print('asdasda');
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      width: 71,
                      height: 71,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      ),
                      child: IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.phone_iphone,
                          size: 30,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  'Phonesss',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: It didn't solve my problem :(

Comment: Code updated, please check

Answer (score 0):

how about you wrap your Container in an expanded...there you have something like...

```
    Column(
        children: [
            InkWell(
                onTap: () async {
                    print('asdasda');
                    },
                 child: Expanded(
                            child:Container(
                                      width: 71,
                                      height: 71,
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                          shape: BoxShape.circle
                                          ),
                                      child: IconButton(
                                          onPressed: () {}, 
                                          icon: Icon(Icons.phone_iphone, 
                                             size: 30, 
                                             color: configColors.homeIcon)
                                          ),
                                     ),
                           ),
                 ),
                   Text('Phonesss')
                 ],
               ),
```